# How to import XML-encoded mxGraph in a Webpack project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, mxgraph

### Context

As part of the migration of a large AngularJS / RequireJS project to Webpack, I've gone through the different parts of the application and adapted the dependencies so that everything works. Well, everything but mxGraph.

### Problem

I can't decode XML-encoded graphs. I've traced the issue to `mxCodec.prototype.decode`, which relies on all functions being in the global scope, decoding XML names with `window[objectName]` to find the relevant function to instantiate objects.

When mxGraph is loaded as a module by Webpack, the objects are not global and not included in the `window` object, hence the decoding doesn't work.

Furthermore, the application relies heavily on mxGraph and it's used in different modules, so it can't be imported in just one place.

Does anyone have a clue how to get this to work?

Thank you in advance for your help.

### Configuration

mxGraph is being imported with Webpack's exports-loader, with a configuration along the lines of

```
rules: {
    test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/mxClient.min.js'),
    use: [
      'exports-loader?' + [
        // handler
        'mxHandle', 'mxVertexHandler', 'mxEdgeSegmentHandler',

        // io
        'mxCodec', 'mxCodecRegistry',

        // layout
        'mxHierarchicalLayout', 'mxSwimlaneLayout',
        'mxCircleLayout', 'mxCompactTreeLayout', 'mxCompositeLayout', 'mxFastOrganicLayout', 'mxGraphLayout',
        'mxLayoutManager', 'mxParallelEdgeLayout', 'mxPartitionLayout', 'mxRadialTreeLayout', 'mxStackLayout',

        // model
        'mxCell', 'mxCellPath', 'mxGeometry', 'mxGraphModel',

        'mxClient',

        // shapes
        'mxActor', 'mxArrow', 'mxArrowConnector', 'mxCloud', 'mxConnector', 'mxCylinder', 'mxDoubleEllipse', 'mxEllipse', 'mxHexagon', 'mxLabel', 'mxLine',
        'mxMarker', 'mxPolyline', 'mxRectangleShape', 'mxRhombus', 'mxRubberband', 'mxStencil', 'mxStencilRegistry', 'mxSwimlane', 'mxText', 'mxTriangle',

        // util
        'mxConstants', 'mxEvent', 'mxUndoManager', 'mxUtils', 'mxDivResizer', 'mxImage', 'mxPoint', 'mxRectangle', 'mxLog',

        // view
        'mxGraph', 'mxEdgeStyle', 'mxCellRenderer', 'mxCellOverlay', 'mxCellState',
      ].join(','),
    ]
  }
```

it's ugly but it allows the application to import mxGraph nicely with a syntax along the lines of `import { mxArrow } from 'mx'`.

### Attempts

- I've tried to solve this by wrapping mxGraph in a custom "mxWrapper" library, which overrides the `mxCodec.prototype.decode` function, but this causes issues further down the line with edges that have control points. It could be that my override doesn't handle mxPoint arrays correctly... but this solution seems very contrived...
- I've also followed [this template](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph-js/tree/master/javascript/examples/webpack) to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work by following the first attempt described above, i.e. writing my own "mxWrapper" library. It's contrived for such a simple need, but it works.

Basic idea:

```
import { 
  mxCell, mxCellPath, mxGeometry, mxGraphModel, mxCodec as _mxCodec, ...
} from 'mx';

// Overridden in our application
var mxCodec = _mxCodec;

var KNOWN_OBJECTS = {
  mxCell: mxCell,
  mxCellPath: mxCellPath,
  mxGeometry: mxGeometry,
  mxGraphModel: mxGraphModel,
  ...
  Array: Array,
  array: Array,
}

/**
 * Function: decode
 *
 * Decodes the given XML node. The optional "into"
 * argument specifies an existing object to be
 * used. If no object is given, then a new instance
 * is created using the constructor from the codec.
 *
 * The function returns the passed in object or
 * the new instance if no object was given.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *
 * node - XML node to be decoded.
 * into - Optional object to be decodec into.
 */
mxCodec.prototype.decode = function (node, into) {
  var obj = null;

  if (node != null && node.nodeType == mxConstants.NODETYPE_ELEMENT) {
    var ctor = null;

    try {
      ctor = KNOWN_OBJECTS[node.nodeName];
    }
    catch (err) {
      // ignore
    }

    var dec = mxCodecRegistry.getCodec(ctor);

    if (dec != null) {
      obj = dec.decode(this, node, into);
    }
    else {
      obj = node.cloneNode(true);
      obj.removeAttribute('as');
    }
  }

  return obj;
};


export {
  mxCell, mxCellPath, mxGeometry, mxGraphModel, ...
};
```

I'm still very open and interested in better ideas...